# Get font face and font type in Python3 from PDF without library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, text

I am trying to find out the font family and font size of text in PDF which contains various lines of different fonts and sizes. Also it has to be compatible with Python 3.5, I'm surprised there is no easy way to do this.

I want something like

```
f = open('a.pdf', 'r')
f.read_line_with_font_and_size()
f.read_line_with_font_and_size()
```

Output can be like this or json

> ("Hello", [("Arial", "23")])
>
> (["How to parse", "**PDF in Python3**"], [("Arial", "20"), ("Calibri", 15, "Bold")])

---

Just to iterate, I'm not looking for libraries. I'm looking for an easy way to read the font size of a pdf file. Pdfminer.six 3rd party library works on Python3 to extract font family and font sizes, but I'm looking for code to do it myself without using that library.

Comment: Asking for a library that helps you do this is unfortunately off-topic here. Have you tried googling around for any possible packages?

Comment: I have edited it to reflect the same